Flip between standalone and replicaset
I've been running a 3 member replicaset for 8 months, but due to failures at a host, 2 members failed.
I got my surviving member to restart in standalone mode.
Question: now that the host failures are resolved, can I restart my surviving member again but now again in replicaset mode (using the original rs name), start the 2 failed hosts again with their respective replicaset configs, and will this then work again as before?

That will likely require you to resync the nodes that were offline for a while, but that should work.

Thank you. Resyncing takes time, but isn’t a problem perse. So no need to “start over” with a new replica set name?

As long as you didn't destroy the replication data in the local database on the surviving node, no

I don’t think did, oplog collection is still there, but I couldn’t find a location where, for example, rs.conf() is stored?

You can try  to copy the entie dbPath content from working node to the failed nodes. Then you may save the initial synch. See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/restore-replica-set-from-backup/#copy-database-files-and-restart--instance

I ended up trying this and failed, most probably due to my own mistake. My primary had the newest data, but was running as standalone. 5 days after the host failure, I started both other nodes again as replicaset members. Then I made the mistake to restart my standalone node (with the most up to date data) in the replicaset. The result was that the replicaset thought that the existing members had the most recent data, and my replicaset "reset" itself to the state of before the host failure. Took a while to catch up again, but no fun.
